# The history of ethylene

Tags: terminology, history-of-chemistry

According to the history section in [Ethylene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethylene), it is written that:

> the name ethylene was used in this sense as early as 1852

However, the earliest mention of it I could find was in 1859 (Wurtz, "Sur l'oxyde d'*ethylene*"; [Comptus Rendus 48](http://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/16550), p.101). I also found mentions of "ethylene" in 1862 (Wurtz, "[...]On oxide of *ethylene*, considered as a link between organic and mineral chemistry[...]"), and in 1878 (Frankland and Thorne, "[...]On the Luminosity of Benzol when burnt with non-luminous Combustible Gases[...]"). Can anyone find any earlier publications that mention "ethylene"?

Comment: I considered ethane, and got the fact that the prefix *eth* comes from ether. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GbRO.png

Comment: Thanks for responding, @PrittBalagopal. However, what I essentially want to know when the word "ethylene" was first used. This may have been unclear in my title; perhaps "etymology" is a slightly inaccurate word.

Comment: For what it's worth, Merriam-Webster says first usage is 1849, but reference is not provided online. Have you checked the Oxford English Dictionary? It is not available free online, but is often the best source for first usages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Oxford English Dictionary entry on "ethylene", the first English usage was in 1849 in the *Chemical Gazette* (alternate name *Journal of Practical Chemistry*), published in London. The specific citation is Vol. 7 p. 116 (Mar. 15, 1849). The sentence in which it is used is in an article by "A. Wurtz" titled "On a Series of Organic Alkalies Homologous with Ammonia.", and the relevant sentence reads "By adding to ammonia the elements of ethylene, $\ce{C4H4}$, ethylic ammonia, $\ce{C4H7N}$, is obtained."

The full text of the journal is available digitally via Google Books.